# Huggingface "transformers" library: Get token amount for piece of text

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I would like to get the number of tokens for a piece of string, so I can split it up if it exceeds the model's maximum length before sending it to OpenAI. For that, I do this:

```py
    from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer

    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    return len(tokenizer.encode(text))
```

it does work, however it often throws the following warning in my console:

> Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum
> sequence length for this model (2551 > 1024). Running this sequence
> through the model will result in indexing errors

I'm aware that the length is > the maximum model length - that's why I'm using this method in the first place.

Is there a way to ignore this warning, or a better way to do this? I want to avoid having this spammed in my console, as I'm spamming more important stuff in the console.

Answer (score 0):

try use "tiktoken"

```
import tiktoken

encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model("gpt2")
encoding.encode("tiktoken is great!")
# [83, 1134, 30001, 318, 1049, 0]
num_tokens = len(encoding.encode("tiktoken is great!"))
# num_tokens = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer submitted by [ozs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14719161/ozs) is what you should go for when you intend to use openai's API, changing the log level to `error` as shown in the following example turns off the warning message in `transformers`:

```py
import transformers

transformers.logging.set_verbosity_error()
```